# Contracting in python

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a program that contracts a list. For example:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 8, 6,]
```

has to be contracted into a list that looks like this:

```
[1, 5, 1, 8, 6, 6]
```

I don't have a clue on how to do this and was hoping that any of you could help me.

I'm given a list that looks like this l1 = [1, 3, 9, 1, 2, 7, 8] and i'm supposed to contract the list into a new list which consist of the old lists nondecending segments extremities. It is supposed to work with any list given.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: what is the logic behind the contraction ?

Comment: More-over, I have *no idea* what the relationship is between the sample input and output.

Comment: Random arbitrary removal of numbers or is there something more sinister at work here?

Comment: I don't understand what contracted means in this context. Your example is not enough to understand what you want to do.
You want someone to do your job you need to at least give him the proper instructions =)

If you want to take a value out of a list you can use the remove() method.

Comment: Random removal and insertion... to make it even more sinister. Zalgo!

Comment: your level of English seems just perfectly fine to be able to explain the problem better—don't hide your laziness/hastiness behind bad language skills :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to understand the question:

> im given a list that looks like this l1 = [1, 3, 9, 1, 2, 7, 8] and im
>   supposed to contract the list by taking the first number then the next
>   bigest and the smallest after that and then the biggest again. This is
>   a school assignment and i have no idea on how to do this. english
>   isn't my first language and it's realy difficult to explain the
>   assignment :/

I supposed that "biggest" and "smallest" refer to local maxima and minima. So a number at index `i` is "biggest" if `l[i-1] < l[i]` and `l[i] > l[i+1]`. "Smallest" the other way around. So basically your are searching for the extrema of a function `N -> N`.

If this is what you want, this should help (considering that start and end points always are extrema):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

def sign(x): return 0 if not x else x // abs(x)

def extrema (l):
    return [l[0]] + [e for i, e in enumerate(l[:-1]) if i and sign(e-l[i-1])==sign(e-l[i+1])] + [l[-1]]

l1 = [1, 3, 9, 1, 2, 7, 8]
print (extrema (l1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is what i needed. I'm going to need to do some reading to understand some of the code. Again, thank you for the help.